# Can't play sound in WPS Office Presentation (Freya)

Tags: release-freya, sound, office

Making a presentation with WPS Office on Freya. When I add background music of sound, they will not play. The mp3s play fine in noise.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

This is most likely to be an issue with WPS rather than with the OS itself.

Could you try using another suite? Libre Office for instance.

Comment: I figured the same, but I can't find the issue on any forum. And since the user of this machine isn't me (It's my Grandma) I don't really want to tell her she has to relearn a different office suite.

Answer (score 0):

WPS is an excellent alternative to MS but its PowerPoint does not support audio/ video insertion or voice recording.
Libreoffice is also great but their PowerPoint templates are the most useless ones. secondly, you cannot import your own templates
so you are stuck in both cases 1. in WPS, you cannot have a ppt with narration 2. in LibreOffice, you cannot have your choice of a template by importing the saved one